# Resistor wattage for HDMI hack

Tags: resistors, hdmi

I need to add a 1K ohm resistor to a HDMI connector to solve some EDID HDMI issues.

Here is the image of the person who already did that.

[image: HDMI connector]

My quesion is: Considering that voltage of pins to connect to resistor is 5V and amperage is (perhaps) 50mA; resistor 1k ohm of what wattage should I purchase? 1/4W, 1/2W, ... ?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I don't know why they suggest to shortcut those pins in that article...

If I will use 1000ohm; with 5V voltage => 5mA will flow through resistor? The power will be 0.025W.

If I will use 1/4W resistor, it will not overheat, right?
1/4W is max value of that specific resistor to work with NO overheat?

[article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/174456)

Answer (score 3):

You can't get 10mA at 5VDC through a 1k resistor.
You can get max of 5mA  (5V / 1000ohm = 0.005A)
Power is I^2 * R:   0.005 * 0.005 * 1000 = 0.025W

You need a minimum of 1/40 of a watt.

Commenters are correct, I meant minimum, not maximum, but I'm fuzzyheaded sometimes :)
Thank you Commenters!

Comment: I'm happy to upvote if you mention 'resistor with minimum power rating of 1/40 Watt' or similar.

Comment: @R Drast:  That should be minimum 1/40 watt - higher power rating is fine.

Comment: I don't know why they suggest to shortcut those pins in that article...

If I will use 1000ohm; with 5V voltage => 5mA will flow through resistor? The power will be 0.025W.

If I will use 1/4W resistor, it will not overheat, right? 1/4W is max value of that specific resistor to work with NO overheat?

Answer (score 0):

P = IV. P is power on watts. Get that wattage or higher resistor.

Comment: I think you mean P=I^2R, or P=E^2/R.  P=VR would mean he needs a 5000 watt resistor.

Comment: @RDrast 5000W resistor would work too ;o) (not accounting for frequency behavior of an actual 5kW resistor)

Comment: Meant V × I not R